# Как решить Cannot set properties of null (setting 'innerHTML')?

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование

HTML:

```
<div class="cart__num" id="cart_num">0</div>
```

JS:

```
var cart__num = document.querySelector(".cart__num");


function addToCart() {
    alert("Добавлено в корзину");

    cart__num.innerHTML = 3;
}
```

Не пойму, что не так

Comment: ошибка указывает не то, что в момент вызова `document.querySelector(".cart__num")` нужного элемента не было в DOM

Answer (score 1):

Как верно указал [Grundy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/186999/grundy), код у вас абсолютно верный и работает, а проблема возникает из-за того, что в *js* вы пытаетесь получить элемент с классом ***.cart__num*** в тот момент, когда он ещё не был объявлен в разметке *html* (возможно, что этот компонент вы создаёте и добавляете в разметку *html* либо позже, либо не на той странице, где идёт вызов *js*).

```js
var cart__num = document.querySelector(".cart__num");

function addToCart() {
    alert("Добавлено в корзину");

    cart__num.innerHTML = 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="cart__num" id="cart_num">0</div>
<button type="submit" id="AddToCart" onclick="addToCart();">Добавить в корзину</button>
```

Comment: Короче, закинул объявление переменной cart__num внутрь функции addToCart и все стало четко